# Geometry Node snap points on grid

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've ran into a problem when using the new "Distribute points in volume" node in geometry node set with the grid distrubution method: the points are not aligned properly with the scene units. I can't figure out how to make it happen. Any help is welcome

Here is how it looks
[image]

All points are offset on all 3 axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's any particular reason why they *would* conform to the grid, it probably gives precedence to the shape and size of the mesh, but if you want to, you can use a `Vector Math` in *Snap* mode to, well, snap their positions to increments of your choosing. If you choose a wider increment than the original grid you would end up with multiple points at the same positions so you might wanna use a `Merge by Distance` afterwards to get rid of unnecessary geometry.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. I had placed a geometry to instance node right before the Set position which didn't allow me to snap the points for some reason. Thanks again

Comment: @Alex When you turn a geometry into an instance, at the moment of its creation its 'origin' is set at [0,0,0], so if you then try to "snap" its position nothing will change since [0,0,0] is already on the grid.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying